# WebStorm and webpack alias not working without slash

Tags: webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using webpack aliases and am attempting to get WebStorm to fully recognize it.

This is my config

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/') + '/',
    },
},
```

The problem I am facing and can't find a solution to, is that when I import a file with this alias: `import router from '@router'` WebStorm won't recognize the `router` file unless I add a slash after the alias: `import router from '@/router'`. It does compile either way.

[image: Import not recognized]

Is there a way to get WebStorm to recognize the file without the slash so I can <kbd>Cmd + click</kbd> to view source? I know its a pretty vain thing to ask for I just like the syntax without the slash a lot more. If not I'll live with it.

Comment: no; webpack aliases are mappings for folders, so a path separator after it is expected

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer, I'll live with it. Thanks